# Facing problem to set service name from env variable in serverless.yml file after upgrading to latest version

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to set the serverless service name from the env file. Before deploying serverless, I have set the value of ECR_NAME as

```
export ECR_NAME=$(echo $CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG | awk -v srch="-" -v repl="" '{ gsub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }')
```

Then I have written it as below in the serverless.yml.

```
service: ${env:CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${env:ECR_NAME}

useDotenv: true
configValidationMode: error
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326
```

Getting the below error:

```
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)
```

Installed version

```
Framework Core: 3.14.0
Plugin: 6.2.1
SDK: 4.3.2
```

Comment: Q: Exactly what kind of "serverless framwork" are you using???  Please specify vendor and product!!!  (I'm guessing AWS Docker/AWS ECR?)

Comment: We are deploying to AWS Lambda and using container image. Serverless Framework version: 2.32.0

We could set the service name dynamically from env variables before version upgrade. Since version 2.32.0, when attempting this, the commands fail with the following error: Cannot resolve serverless.yml: "service" property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage).

Comment: please update your current status

Answer (score 2):

See Issue #9313 on GitHub:

> https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9813
>
> **Problem:**
>
> The latest version of the serverless framework is no longer working
> for AWS Lambda deployments and is throwing the following error:
>
> ```
> Cannot resolve serverless.yml: “provider.stage” property is not accessible (configured behind variables which cannot be resolved at this stage)
> ```
>
> **Discussion:**
>
> with the new resolver, such definition is not supported. In general,
> it is discouraged to configure stage behind env variables for example,
> as at the point where stage is going to be resolved, not whole env
> might be available (e.g. loading env vars from .env.{stage} needs to
> resolve stage first in order to properly load variables from file),
> which might introduce bugs that are hard to debug. Also, the
> provider.stage serves more as a "default" stage and --stage flag via
> CLI is the preferred way of setting it.
>
> ...
>
> In your configuration file you explicitly opt-in to use new resolver
> via variablesResolutionMode: 20210326 variable.
>
> We are not discouraging the use of env variables - quite the contrary,
> we've been promoting them as a replacement for custom CLI options for
> example and it is generally a great practice to use them. As for env
> source for stage specifically, this has been introduced as a fix, as
> stage should be already resolved before we attempt env variables
> resolution, as loading .env files can depend on stage property.
> @medikoo I know we've talked about it today, do you think it could be
> safe to resolve stage from env source in specific circumstances (e.g.
> when dotenv is not used)?
>
> **See also:**
>
> - https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#new-variables-resolver
> - https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/